# How do I install Neo2 on Chrome OS?

Tags: google-chrome-os

I tried using Neo2 on my Chromebook, but it is buggy and does not work. Any idea on a) how to fix this, b) how to install it manually (Chrome OS has a Linux terminal) or c) how to manually add a keyboard layout?

When activating Neo2 it does not type letters but activates numbers and arrow keys.

EDIT: it seems to be activating the fourth layer.

Answer (score 0):

I will leave this question on here because it took me a while to figure out. The keyboard launches right away into the 4th layer. This can be fixed by pressing shift and alt. However, now I am struggling to use the 3rd layer. I am assuming this is because Chromebooks lack certain keys that are very important for the normal Neo2 layout. Any ideas on how to solve this?